# How do I include compiled classes from one maven module to another one?

Tags: java, maven

I have the following project structure:

```
billing-project
|-- billing-shared
|    |
|    +-- pom.xml
|         
|-- billing-console-configurator
|    |
|    +-- pom.xml
|    
|-- billing-webapp
|    |
|    +-- pom.xml
|    
+-- pom.xml
```

`pom.xml` inside `billing-console-configurator` has the following dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.example.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>billing-shared</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And my `billing-console-configurator` projects uses classes from `billing-shared`, IDE and maven successfully compile `billing-console-configurator`. But when I look at `billing-console-configurer-1.0.jar` I can't find let's say `SettingsHolder` class which is located inside `billing-shared` module.

The question is how to make classes from the `billing-shared` to be packaged inside `billing-console-configurator`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Comment: thanks, worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Classes which are located inside the `billing-shared` module will be packaged in the jar specified by `package com.billing.shared` (assuming you have the package definition). You can achieve the same effect by defining both classes in `billing-shared` and `billing-console-configurator` in the same package, so they are packaged in the same archive file.